# Can I find an exact child window with WS_VISIBLE window style

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Can I find an exact child window in another application if I know that this window should have WS_VISIBLE window style? I don't know how can I use this in case of FindWindow / FindWindowEx functions.

Comment: You could use `EnumChildWindows`, checking the attributes of each window inside the `EnumChildProc` that you supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do this, but only indirectly. The API won't check the condition for you. You have to do it.

Use EnumChildWindows or FindWindowEx to walk through the children. Then check the windows styles of each window that you find until you meet the one that you are looking for.